# Golang benchmark: why does allocs/op show 0 B/op?

Tags: go

Here is a code snippet for benchmark:

```
// bench_test.go

package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkHello(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        a := 1
        a++
    }
}
```

The metric `allocs/op` shows 0 B/op. variable `a` is an int type and doesn't take too much memory, but it should not take zero B.

```
> go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: a
BenchmarkHello-4    2000000000           0.26 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      a   0.553s
```

Comment: If your question is "What does memory allocation mean?" please ask that question. Your question is otherwise a duplicate of the one you linked to.

Comment: The reason your allocs/op is 0, is probably because your for loop is a no-op, so gets optimized away by the compiler, so no memory is allocated.

Comment: Hi @Flimzy I have changed the title of this question based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this metric allocs/ops zero?

---

> ```
> package main
>
> import (
>   "testing"
> )
>
> func BenchmarkHello(b *testing.B) {
>   for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
>       a := 1
>       a++
>   }
> }
> ```

---

The allocs/ops average only counts heap allocations, not stack allocations.

The allocs/ops average is rounded down to the nearest integer value.

The Go gc compiler is an optimizing compiler. Since

```
{
    a := 1
    a++
}
```

doesn't accomplish anything, it is elided.

Answer (score 0):

> The benchmark tool only reports heap allocations. Stack allocations via escape analysis are less costly, possibly free, so are not reported.

### Reference

[Why is this simple benchmark showing zero allocations?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/3uVS3wxAmzI)

Comment: Dave Cheney is not the author of Go.

Comment: This is a long list. And while maybe legally correct it is nothing to state.

Comment: It's more accurate to say that Dave Cheney is a Go contributor. But then anyone can be, so that's not very meaningful, either. He currently has [476](https://github.com/golang/go/commits?author=davecheney) commits to his name, most recently in 2017, in contrast with the 40,632 total commits. So perhaps you can say Dave Cheney authored 1.17% of Go.